# add .htaccess a trailing slash and css got awful

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'd like to put a trailing slash to my url with `.htaccess`

My `.htaccess` is

```
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
        RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
        RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

When I try to use `www.example.com/about-us` it works fine but when the Url is `www.example.com/about-us/` my css url won't load the website get horrible. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: You should move your last 2 RewriteConditions above your first RewriteCond

Comment: What's even easier is to remove the trailing slashes. Like [Laravel](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess#L9) does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use absolute URL's or use the base tag in the head section of your site after doing those `pretty URL` rewrites.

With CSS use `/` before the path.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/to/style.css">
```

Or you can use the base.

```
<head>
<base href="http://www.example.com/">
</head>
```